# Bootstrap `popover-content` not determining height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im in the process of making a multi-level multi-column dropdown using bootstraps `popover`

The problem I am running into is that I am using multiple `popover-title`'s as the heading of each category but the height will be wrong if there are too many links in the `popover-content` content above it.

Whenever i inspect i can see the height of `popover-content` isnt set to anything is there anyway to have this set to reflect the actual height of the div?

Here is a **[Codepen](http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/RrbGgW?editors=110)** of what i have so far Ive only started on the "A little bit of everything" sub menu

I've tried doing

```
.nav.departments .popover-content{
  height: 55px;
}
```

And this works but it is not dynamic i have to set a fixed height for every section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of giving a fixed height to the div for proper displaying of the content use display table instead.

```
.nav.departments .popover-content
    {
      display: table;
    }
```

-Thanks